# How do I send all calls from a contact to voicemail in Android 7 (LG phone)?

Tags: contacts, calls, voicemail

Searched here and on the internet and either the options have changed or my LG phone does not have the option. Seems like the old way to do it was to press the Overflow button while editing the contact, then select "all calls to voicemail".

Carrier is TMobile.

[image: overflow]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should still be able to accomplish this through a different route.

being that you are using an LG on T-Mobile, I'll give you instructions from [T-Mobile's website](https://support.t-mobile.com/docs/DOC-30609) on how it's done on an LG G5.

Go to your phone settings  → calls  → decline and reject calls. Now press on the plus (+) symbol, and add the desired contacts.

Calls from numbers on the reject list, are automatically forwarded to your voicemail.

Comment: @acejavelin great point! I edited the answer with a confirmation from T-Mobile's website that this works on an lgg5. I'll have to hear from op if they have a different phone

Comment: @acejavelin is that something that they removed from the g5 plus, recently? Cuz according to [this post](https://androidforums.com/threads/moto-g5-plus-how-to-block-phone-number.1137979/) it should work.

Comment: Lol... I swear I looked and didn't see it before I commented earlier, but sure enough it's there now. I will delete my earlier comment.

Comment: Ugh if a contact has multiple phone numbers you have to select each one! My "Ignore" contact has 15 numbers in it! So lame, so much easier the old way.

Comment: @jcollum well that's up to lg. On my Galaxy s5 it's still there. If this answers your question feel free to accept the answer.